# ImportError: cannot import name 'MovingAverage' from 'darts.models'

Tags: python, dart, importerror

When I try to import MovingAverage, I get an import error.

`ImportError: cannot import name 'MovingAverage' from 'darts.models' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/darts/models/__init__.py)`

Of course, I did install darts.

`!pip install darts`

Here's a snippet of the source code

```
from darts.models import MovingAverage
# Oil Price

oil = TimeSeries.from_dataframe(df_oil, time_col = 'date', value_cols = ['dcoilwtico'], freq = 'D')

oil = oil.astype(np.float32)

# Transform
oil_filler = MissingValuesFiller(verbose=False, n_jobs=-1, name="Filler")
oil_scaler = Scaler(verbose=False, n_jobs=-1, name="Scaler")
oil_pipeline = Pipeline([oil_filler, oil_scaler])
oil_transformed = oil_pipeline.fit_transform(oil)

# Moving Averages for Oil Price
oil_moving_average_7 = MovingAverage(window=7)
oil_moving_average_28 = MovingAverage(window=28)
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the version of darts?

`pip show darts`

I recommend starting with checking the version of darts you have installed and ensuring it's the latest version or the one that includes the MovingAverage class.

Here is my output where I ran your code snippet and the Import error resolved after running `!pip install darts`:

```
Name: darts
Version: 0.27.0
Summary: A python library for easy manipulation and forecasting of time series.
Home-page: https://unit8co.github.io/darts/
Author: 
Author-email: 
License: Apache License 2.0
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages
Requires: holidays, joblib, matplotlib, nfoursid, numpy, pandas, pmdarima, pyod, pytorch-lightning, requests, scikit-learn, scipy, shap, statsforecast, statsmodels, tbats, tensorboardX, torch, tqdm, typing-extensions, xarray, xgboost
Required-by:
```

If darts is not installed correctly, you can run

```
pip uninstall darts
pip install darts
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentations](https://unit8co.github.io/darts/generated_api/darts.models.filtering.moving_average_filter.html), there is only `MovingAverageFilter` or `NaiveMovingAverage`. Not `MovingAverage`. If you would like to return the new filtered time series, do this:

```py
from darts.models.filtering.moving_average_filter import MovingAverageFilter
```

Full example using [Brent oil prices](https://www.kaggle.com/code/kylewalden/time-series-forecasting-brent-oil-prices/data?select=BrentOilPrices.csv) (suit to your needs):

```py
from darts import TimeSeries
from darts.models.filtering.moving_average_filter import MovingAverageFilter
from darts.utils.missing_values import fill_missing_values
from darts.dataprocessing.transformers.scaler import Scaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Load data
df_oil = pd.read_csv("../data/BrentOilPrices.csv")
oil = TimeSeries.from_dataframe(df_oil, time_col="Date", value_cols="Price", freq="D")
oil = oil.astype(np.float32)

# Fill missing values
oil_filler = fill_missing_values(oil)

# Scale the time series
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1, 1))
transformer = Scaler(scaler)
oil_filler_scaled = transformer.fit_transform(oil_filler)

# Moving Averages for Oil Price
oil_moving_average_7 = MovingAverageFilter(window=7)
oil_moving_average_28 = MovingAverageFilter(window=28)
oil_moving_average_365=MovingAverageFilter(window=365)

# Apply filters and assign to new variables
oil_ma_7_filtered = oil_moving_average_7.filter(oil_filler_scaled)
oil_ma_28_filtered = oil_moving_average_28.filter(oil_filler_scaled)
oil_ma_365_filtered = oil_moving_average_365.filter(oil_filler_scaled)
oil_ma_7_filtered.plot()
oil_ma_28_filtered.plot()
oil_ma_365_filtered.plot()
```

[image]

Hope that answers your question.